# Stratified random sampling on multiple variables

Tags: r, sampling, tidymodels

I'm using tidymodels in R and need to perform stratified sampling on two variables for splitting into training and testing data. Reproducible code below uses a single column 'cyl'. How can I sample using both 'cyl' and  'gear'?

```
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)

split <- initial_split(mtcars, prop = 0.7, strata = cyl)
train <- split %>%  training()
test <- split %>%  testing()
```

Comment: There are some [github issues](https://github.com/tidymodels/rsample/issues/94) related to this

Comment: I guess I'll try to group the variables: 

`mtcars$group <- interaction(mtcars[, c('cyl', 'gear')]);
split <- initial_split(mtcars, prop = 0.7, strata = group)`